# Can I add handle ties to QO tandem breakers?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

This is a follow up to [Why does a single pole tandem breaker allow connecting the switch handles?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/175980/why-does-a-single-pole-tandem-breaker-allow-connecting-the-switch-handles) which was asking what circumstances handle-tied tandem breakers would ever be useful. (There are some good reasons.)

Some answers to that question raised the issue: is it actually "permissible" to tie two QO tandem breakers together yourself? Such as a QOTO2020.

By permissible I mean: strictly allowed by the manufacturer & therefore to code. (I'm sure you could rig something up but if you want to do it by the book & know that it is safe, that may not cut it.)

Answer (score 2):

### This is OK, as the manufacturer has a specific part for this job

Handle-tying the two *inner* half-breakers in a pair of (modern style) QO tandem breakers is legal, no different than handle-tying two full-size breakers save for a change in part number: instead of a QO1HT (the normal QO handle tie), you need a [QOTHT](https://www.schneider-electric.us/en/product/QOTHT/qo-mini-breaker-accy%2C-handle-tie%2C-1-pole%2C-120-240-vac/) instead (image from Square-D's product page):

[image: QOTHT picture]

Answer (score 1):

The information I have been able to find seems inconsistent / incomplete.

For QO breakers there **is** a handle tie from the manufacturer (Square D / Schneider Electric), which is part [QO1HT](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_enDocType=Instruction%20sheet&p_File_Name=40271-902-05.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=40271-902-05).

[image]

However the [documentation](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_enDocType=Instruction%20sheet&p_File_Name=40271-902-05.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=40271-902-05) is sparse and doesn't state which specific breakers this is meant for. I was expecting an exact listing, much like you would see for a panel calling out which breakers you could use.

[A catalog document](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_enDocType=Catalog&p_File_Name=0730CT9801.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=0730CT9801) does state "*Converts any two adjacent 120/240 Vac 1P QO circuit breakers to independent trip 2P.* " Based on that you might assume its OK to use their handle tie with any single pole QO breaker. But there is contradictory information. At least I found a comment posted by the manufacturer to a customer question stating:

> From SchneiderCustomerCare:
>
> April 27, 2016
>
> ...the QO1HTCP is only for the QO load centers. We
>   offer the HOM1HT for the Homeline. However **neither will tie Tandem
>   breakers together. We do not offer a breaker tie for your requested
>   application**.

([source](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-QO-Circuit-Breaker-Handle-Tie-QO1HTCP/100165878))

(Not sure why they use a slightly different product # in that comment, though it seems like the same thing. Might be because it is sold in a qty > 1).

So if in doubt, probably a call to the manufacturer would be in order.

And though this is just about QO breakers I'd be circumspect about any brand / model unless the instructions are crystal clear.

Comment: The part you're after is a [QOTHT](https://www.schneider-electric.us/en/product/QOTHT/qo-mini-breaker-accy%2C-handle-tie%2C-1-pole%2C-120-240-vac/)

Comment: QO handle ties are used on breakers that are on adjacent poles. Square D only has 1 quad that I can remember it is a 20303020. This provides a 30 amp double pole and 2 single 20’s in 2 standard slots using the handle tie. Get prepared for some sticker shock these are spendy. But the ties are listed for use on adjacent poles, I don’t think you could even force them into a parallel tandem. They used to make inline tandems I thought they were better but you don’t see them anymore. Where are these used, multiwire branch circuits , or any place a common trip was not required.

Comment: @EdBeal -- the QO20303020 is the only packaged kit for quadplexes in QO.  In other cases, you have to buy the two tandem breakers and the QOTHT yourself

Comment: I agree but finding left and right tandems other than this is tough, I have a few in-line style that are easier to even make 2 double pole handle tied possibilities, with side by side tandems  , square D only has 1 possible configuration. No twin double pole like other brands have, but I still prefer square D because they are professional and top end residential with the same breaker, have installed thousands. But for home types doubling up may be easier with other brands I agree.

Answer (score 1):

> By permissible I mean: strictly allowed by the manufacturer & therefore to code.

Code has no problem with handle-tying.  The issue is whether the manufacturer will offer it and will UL list it.  Those two processes do the vetting as to whether it is safe.

> (I'm sure you could rig something up but if you want to do it by the book & know that it is safe, that may not cut it.)

Exactly...  If the manufacturer doesn't offer it, there's a fair chance it cannot be made safe.  They wouldn't put themselves at a market disadvantage if they didn't have to.  If they do offer it, shrug, might as well use it.

You can also try a "Classified" breaker, for instance if QO won't offer it, try Siemens QD or  Eaton CHQ.

Comment: Square d handle ties are not plastic but a metal spindle. Most other handle ties are metal clips. I am sure you can find some but most are metal that lock in place once pressed on. Today it is cheaper to purchase a common trip breaker than a handle tie.

Comment: I think you misread the second quoted text (or I wrote it unclearly). I was saying that a DIY handle tie probably could not be safe.

Comment: As far as the "to code" part goes - I was thinking about the rule that code requires you to follow manufacturer's instructions.